# The Capability to choose post template in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a role in wordpress with `add_role( string $role, string $display_name, array $capabilities = array() )`
 function I want to know witch Capability from the array of `$capabilities` will give it access to choose post template?

This is my code:

```
    $capabilities = array(
"activate_plugins" => false,
"create_users" => false,
"delete_themes" => false,
"delete_users" => false,
"edit_files" => false,
"edit_plugins" => false,
"edit_theme_options" => false,
"edit_themes" => false,
"edit_users" => false,
"export" => false,
"import" => false,
"install_plugins" => false,
"install_themes" => false,
"list_users" => false,
"manage_options" => false,
"promote_users" => false,
"remove_users" => false,
"switch_themes" => false,
"update_core" => false,
"update_plugins" => false,
"update_themes" => false,
"edit_dashboard" => false,
"customize" => false,
"delete_site" => false,
"moderate_comments" => false,
"manage_categories" => false,
"manage_links" => false,
"edit_others_posts" => true,
"edit_pages" => false,
"edit_others_pages" => false,
"edit_published_pages" => false,
"publish_pages" => false,
"delete_pages" => false,
"delete_others_pages" => false,
"delete_published_pages" => false,
"delete_others_posts" => true,
"delete_private_posts" => true,
"edit_private_posts" => true,
"read_private_posts" => true,
"delete_private_pages" => false,
"edit_private_pages"=> false,
"read_private_pages" => false,
"unfiltered_html"=> false,
"edit_published_posts"  => true,
"upload_files" => true,
"publish_posts" => true,
"delete_published_posts" => true,
"edit_posts" => true,
"delete_posts" => true,
"read" => true  );
 add_role( "parisa", "parisa", $capabilities );
```

I want to know witch one to set to true?

Comment: you mean by post template the theme ?

Comment: You may have more help for that on the site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: no in the edit post you have an option to choose between costume post templates that you have created!

Comment: can you add an image of your back office for this option

Answer (score 0):

A user with the capability of Create/Edit/Delete posts may access to choose post template.For more, please visit [Roles and Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

Hope this will helps you.